# How do I determine whether or not a vector in Octave already contains a given value?

Tags: vector, octave

I am trying to implement a Composite Trapezoid Rule in Octave, and at one part of the iteration I check to see whether or not an element is already in a one-dimensional vector. Would I use the all or any utility functions in some way to accomplish this?

Comment: use `ismember()` or `any (x == elem)`

Comment: If you want to check if a var is already declared use 'if (exist ("foo", "var))'

Comment: Is it worth a quick check to make sure that the trapezoid rule won't simply add zero in this case, the volume of a zero width trapezoid if an element is repeated in the vector of the x-coordinates of the slices (the deltas of which define the widths)?